# ubuntu16.04 python2.7 Installation error

Tags: python-2.7

```
easy_install pywin32
error: can't create or remove files in install directory
```

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/test-easy-install-4860.write-test'
```

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
```

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.

Comment: You need to use `sudo` if you want to install the package system-wide. BTW, `pywin32` will not work for linux. It's only for windows.

Comment: pip install pywin32
Collecting pywin32
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pywin32

Comment: You cannot install pywin32 in ubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

Try with `sudo` but you can install Python with `apt-get`  like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes-python2.7
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install python2.7
```